# How to make my discord bot to read other bot embed messages

Tags: bots, discord.js

I have favorite discord bot game called "EPIC RPG" there's an event for players, so I wanted to make a bot that can announce the event with mention a specific role and adding some messages,  i need your ideas pls,

Here's my code

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.id === '555955826880413696') {
    if (message.embeds) {
      const embed = message.embeds[0]
      if (embed.title === "**IT'S RAINING COINS**") {
        return  message.channel.send('the COIN RAIN event is started')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

that code is according to this picture, cuz I wanna trigger the command with the **IT'S RAINING COINS** statement and reply with "the coin rain event is started" https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5mjN.png, the problem is my bot cant read the embed messages, any ideas?

PS : when I started it, it shows that word `title` on `if (embed.title === "Theblablabla` is undefined

Comment: What have you tried? What errors did you get? Please provide some code for us. [How to Ask](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask&ved=2ahUKEwj86bf7_KHrAhVx0FkKHUkzATYQFjAAegQICBAD&usg=AOvVaw00xttYhbqoB7L7CXC05R8r)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the picture, the title of the embed isn't just a text but there is also an emoji: [image]

You should change the `embed.title === "**IT'S RAINING COINS**"`

to `embed.title.includes("IT'S RAINING COINS")`

Final result:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.id === '555955826880413696') {
    if (message.embeds.length == 1) {
      const embed = message.embeds[0]
      if (embed.title.includes("IT'S RAINING COINS")) {
        return  message.channel.send('the COIN RAIN event is started')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined``` this is what happen after i changed, any idea?

Comment: Because your check condition is wrong, discord API always provide an embed array. You need to check if this array isn't empty. I've edited the code.

Comment: OH ITS WORK SIR OMFG THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: but I have a problem again lol, it seems the word "**IT'S RAINING COINS" is on field, not title, what should I do to detect spesific word from a fields?thanks

Comment: Same but replace with embed.fields[0].title
And make sure that the embed has 1 field.