# How detect specific word on embed message in discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

I'm trying to make a reminder bot for "EPIC RPG" player in my server, there's an event that hosted randomly by the "EPIC RPG" staffs, so I decided to make an announce bot if there's an event

Here's my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => { 
  let embed = message.embeds[0];
  if (embed) {  
  message.channel.send( "<@&734426095759130674>" +"\:moneybag:" + "**CATCH**" + "\:moneybag:" );
  }
  });
```

As you can see my command is triggered on every embed message from every bot, all I want is to trigger by a specific word from "EPIC RPG"bot-like "**IT'S RAINING COINS**" just like the picture below, any ideas?

[image: this is the image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my discord bot to read other bot embed messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447411).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort through the fields and check if it is in one of the fields.

```
  const embed = message.embeds[0];
  if(!embed) return;
  let foundText = false;
  embed.fields.forEach(f => {
     if(f.name.includes('IT\'S RAINING COINS')) foundText = true;
  });
  if (embed && embed.title.includes('IT\'S RAINING COINS')) {  
   message.channel.send( "<@&734426095759130674>" +"\:moneybag:" + "**CATCH**" + "\:moneybag:" );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use embed.title to get the title of the embed, where it says it is raining coins.**

You can also get other information such as the description with embed.description.
[Discord.js MessageEmbed Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)

You can check the embed information using something like:

```js
client.on('message', message => { 
  let embed = message.embeds[0];
  if (embed && embed.title.includes('IT\'S RAINING COINS')) {  
   message.channel.send( "<@&734426095759130674>" +"\:moneybag:" + "**CATCH**" + "\:moneybag:" );
  }
});
```

Comment: the problem is the word "**IT'S RAINING COINS" is on fields not title, thanks

Comment: ```js MessageEmbed {   type: 'rich',   title: undefined,   description: undefined,   url: undefined,   color: 10181046,   timestamp: null,   fields: [     {       value: 'Type **CATCH** (once) to collect some coins! The reward depend on how much players join\n' +         '**Coins per player: 2650 ~ 117600**',       name: "**IT'S RAINING COINS <:coin:541384484201693185>**",       inline: false     }   ],   thumbnail: null,   image: null,   video: null,   author: null,   provider: null,   footer: null,   files: [] }``` here's the embed, as u can see the ITS RAINING COINS is on field, thanks