# read other bots embeds with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, embed

how do we do this in python? [reading other bot embed in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447411/how-to-make-my-discord-bot-to-read-other-bot-embed-messages).. i wanna do the exact same thing but i have no clue, could not find any docs which mention reading other bot's embed.. any help is appreciated please.

```js
if (message.embeds.length == 1) {
      const embed = message.embeds[0]
      if (embed.title.includes("IT'S RAINING COINS")) {
```

the above code is in javascript, i'm tryna do this in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to read documentation then, given a `discord.Message` object, this would roughly be the equivalent:

```py
if len(message.embeds) == 1:
   embed = message.embeds[0]
   if "IT'S RAINING COINS" in embed.title:
      pass
```